# Lost Mines of Phandelver as PC base

Tags: dnd-5e, lost-mine-of-phandelver

I am DMing Lost Mines of Phandelver, and it's looking like the party wants to keep the cave as a base to replace the BBEG and turn evil.

Main question is: if I decide to let them fix up the *forge of spells* after a few quests for parts, what level / how challenging should this be?

I love the rule of unintended consequences, but am not sure of any down sides.

> They let Sildar fail his death saves and bleed out while writing a letter of recommendation for a bugbear. So, yeah, evil.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the RPG Stack Exchange. Unfortunately, idea-generation questions are a pretty poor fit for our format here. The Stack works best with questions that have a definite answer...either based on personal experience, an understanding of the rules, etc. If you have a specific problem you're trying to solve, this is a great place for it...but if you need help coming up with ideas, perhaps a forum or Reddit would be a better place.